# is there a way to grep or parse an ansible variable

Tags: parsing, grep, ansible

I have a variable which i need to parse to pull out a version string, is there a way to do this?  Below is an example of the ansible variable.

```
--xxx 1.2.3-102 --yyy 2.5.10-47 --zzz 10.4.2-193
```

Update: Adding ansible task format

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get Version
    shell: echo '{{ version }}'
    register: results
  - set_fact:
      value: "{{ results.stdout | regex_search(regexp,'') }}"
    vars:
      regexp: ''
  - debug:
      var: value
```

Comment: you need to use regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getting just the version number after "--yyy", alter the regular expression as needed for your task:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get Version
    shell: echo '--xxx 1.2.3-102 --yyy 2.5.10-47 --zzz 10.4.2-193'
    register: results
  - name: set regex
    set_fact:
      re: '--yyy\s+(?P<digit>\d+\.\d+\.\d+-\d+)'
  - set_fact:
      value: "{{ results.stdout | regex_search(re, '\\g<digit>') }}" 
  - debug:
      var: value[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

|m-p solution works great for the latest version of ansible, unfortunately I have to use ansible pre 2.0 (1.9.6) which doesn't seem to support regex_search for some strange reason.

In that case I will use the following

```
"{{ results | regex_replace ('((xxx|yyy)\\s[\\S]+)|(--|zzz|\\s)','') | join }}"
```